# HaProxy + docker health-checks restart dead containers

Tags: node.js, docker, haproxy

this is a rather conceptual question. I am running three node.js webservers as Docker containers behind a HaProxy instance, also in a docker container. The containers get started by docker-compose, so everything pretty standard.

**My problem**: HaProxy does health checks to see if one of my node.js containers dies to redirect traffic, so far so good. But I cannot find a good solution on how to restart dead containers automatically.

Are there any good practices for this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `--retry=always` policy when you run the container so that upon exit it will be automatically restarted by docker daemon.

Take a look at [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart) for more details on restart policies.

Answer (score 1):

You can start special container `willfarrell/autoheal` that monitors and restarts unhealthy containers labeled with `autoheal` label on the host.

```
docker run -d \
  --name autoheal \
  --restart=always \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
  willfarrell/autoheal
```

See https://github.com/willfarrell/docker-autoheal for details.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try to setup [sensu](http://sensuapp.org) for configure same helth checks and to restart unhelth containers.

Answer (score 0):

While running the docker images just mention

```
restart: always
```

Option in your `docker-compose.yaml` file